# Convert query response to List of object DynomoDB c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting result set from dynomoDb using QueryResponse. How can I convert this response to list of object?

```
 var _response = await _client.QueryAsync(_request);
 List<Attendence> businessunits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Attendence>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_response.Items));
```

This is not working for me, Please help me to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got solution for this,

```
 var _response = await _client.QueryAsync(_request);
 using (DynamoDBContext dbcontext = new DynamoDBContext(_client))
 {
      foreach (var item in _response.Items)
      {
           var doc = Document.FromAttributeMap(item);
           var myModel = dbcontext.FromDocument<Attendence>(doc);
           attendence.Add(myModel);
      }
  }
```